# Where can I find JQuery UI css icons?

Tags: jquery

This is a really dumb question but where do I find the JQ date picker icons? I have the ui css file and have noticed that the image links in that file point to a dir that is non existent within my tree. I went to the ui site and can see some icons at the bottom of the site that look like what I need but I can't seem to download them by right clicking. I can get the images if I really wanted to but it makes me wonder if there is an easier way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/?new=454545&w=256&h=240&f=png&fltr[]=rcd|256&fltr[]=mask|icons/icons.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming

and

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/static/icons.html

Comment: I have been there and downloaded a custom theme but all that is ever included in the zip file is an index.html file. I see no ui-css file, icons or even the jquery-ui.js file. I don't know if it's an issue with my compression utility or what.

Comment: Images are a sprite: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/themes/base/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png